# Seamless table name changes in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, naming-conventions

Okay, so I am new to the Rails environment and I am helping to get a project ready for deployment.

And, to make the tables more representative we need to change the names, the problem is the ubiquity at which they appear in the application code.

I have searched for a solution to find-and-replace these in a more batch oriented and time saving way but haven't come up with anything (one of the issues is the naming conventions in rails itself).

I was wondering if there is a solution to this issue that doesn't involve going through the code line by line.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to change the table names only? Or the table _and_ model names? If the table names, you will want to create a migration. If you mean model names (and filenames), you will want to use `sed` for search-and-replace. However, this can be dangerous if not done correctly. If you are using version control, you can always revert quickly

Answer (score 0):

You could easily change the model names, while leaving the table names untouched.  Just make sure you include `self.table_name  = :your_table_name` in the model.